# Merge multiple rows with same ID but different data into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I merge multiple rows with same ID but different data  into one row.

I have table:

```
ORDER_ID  MATERIAL  PLAN_QTY    STATUS
3         A         13          OPEN
3         B         13          OPEN
3         C         13          OPEN
3         D         13          CLOSE
3         E         13          OPEN
3         F         13          OPEN
3         G         13          OPEN
4         A         1000        OPEN
4         B         1000        OPEN
4         C         1000        OPEN
4         D         1000        OPEN
4         E         1000        OPEN
4         F         1000        OPEN
4         G         1000        OPEN
5         A         500         CLOSE
5         B         500         CLOSE
5         C         500         CLOSE
5         D         500         CLOSE
5         E         500         CLOSE
5         F         500         CLOSE
5         G         500         CLOSE
```

I want to get table like this :

```
ORDER_ID    PLAN_QTY    STATUS
3           13          IN-PROGRESS
4           1000        OPEN
5           500         CLOSE
```

Comment: By "merge", do you mean if both "OPEN" and "CLOSE" exist against any given ORDER_ID/PLAN_QTY combination, it is "IN PROGRESS", otherwise it is the single status?

Comment: @ZLK I mean if in Order ID 3, got both "Open" and "Close", the status should be "In-Progress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY, 
CASE WHEN MAX([STATUS]) = MIN([STATUS]) THEN MAX([STATUS]) ELSE 'IN-PROGRESS' END [Status])
FROM tbl
GROUP BY 
ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY;
```

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` clause with conditional aggregation

```
select ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY,
       (case when count(distinct STATUS) > 1 then 'IN-PROGRESS' else             
       (select top 1 STATUS from table where ORDER_ID = t.ORDER_ID) end) as STATUS 
from table t
group by ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY;
```

In other way use only aggregation function

```
select ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY,
       (case when max(STATUS) <> min(STATUS) 
             then 'IN-PROGRESS' else max(STATUS) end) as STATUS 
from table t
group by ORDER_ID, PLAN_QTY;
```

Comment: I think you probably need a `count(distinct` rather than a regular count. `MAX` might also serve better than a subquery since you're already grouping.